# Modular exponential equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am (re)studying congruence and I wanted to solve

> $$8^n + 5^n \equiv  13^n\; \mod 7, \;n\in\mathbb{N}$$

I have computed all the possible remainders

For $8^n \equiv 1 \mod 7$ for any $n$

$5^n$ can give $5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 1$ then repeats indefinitely

$13^n$ can give $6, 1$ then repeats

So the sum $8^n + 5^n \equiv 6 \mod 7$ and $13^n \equiv 6 \mod 7$ when $n=6k+1,\;\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$

My question is

> Are there properties and theorems to solve this equation in a easier
>   way?

Comment: With *Lil' Fermat*, there are only 6 cases to consider fro $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a detail, but the first thing that I would do would be to use the facts that $8\equiv1\pmod7$, $5\equiv-2\pmod 7$, and $13\equiv-1\pmod7$ and re-write the equation as $1+(-2)^n\equiv(-1)^n\pmod7$.

Comment: Now validate for $n\pmod{\phi(7)},$ But $n$ can not be even